# Opacity 1 - elements disappearing. HTML CSS

Tags: html, css, background, opacity

I'm trying to learn HTML and CSS at the moment, and i am doing myself a site.
I used for the background picture

```
min-height: 100%;
min-width: 1024px;

width: 100%;
height: auto;

position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
```

and i want to make a div opaque in order to add some photos on it.

For the rest of the divs in the site i used

background-color: black;

opacity: 0.8;

The problem is that when using opacity: 1; on the div which should contain the photos, the div dissapears (it appears for a split second behind the main background image).
I understand that opacity transfers from parent to child divs but i had just deleted all classes and made each div transparent by pasting those 2 lines of code and the div which i need with opacity: 1; still disappears under the background.
Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using rgba colors to make things opaque, or you can use opaque pictures (pngs for example).

You would use rgba like this:

```
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
```

the 0.5 says how much opaque it will be, the 0,0,0 is black - change that to any color you want.

Comment: same thing is happening, now the element disappears even though it's not 1. it disappears even at 0.9 0.8 etc ...